# How to save changes created by "user" for each user separately using Java/JSF/Hibernate H2 DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I have a following problem and I am not sure how to solve it.

I am writing a basic newsfeed agregator webapp, where the "publisher" can make new topics with news and the reader can subscribe topics and so read the news from those topics he subscribes. He can then mark them as read.

I am writing this with Hibernate H2 database, JSF/Java  and I have a problem. My code looks like this:

This is the entity of Person:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findPerson", query = "SELECT e FROM Person e")


public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String TemporalType = null;
@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

private Long id;

private String name;
private String pw;
private String checkPw;
private String type;
private String topic;
private ArrayList<String> myTopics;

public Person(String name, String pw) {
    this.name = name;
    this.pw = pw;
}

//setters and getters
```

This is my personcontroller class, where I have my login and register method, they should save the user in session (i hope).

```
@Named(value = "personController")
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PersonController {

@EJB
private PersonEJB personEJB;
private Person person = new Person();
private List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
NewsController nc = new NewsController();
private ArrayList<String> myTopics;

public Person login(String name, String pw) {
    Person akt = new Person();

    for (int i = 0; i < getPersonList().size(); ++i) { 
        akt = getPersonList().get(i);
        if (akt.getName().equals(name)) {
            if (akt.getPw().equals(pw)) {
                return akt;
            }
        }
    }
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("user", person);
    return null;
}

public boolean register(String name, String pw, String checkPw, String type) {

        for (int i = 0; i < getPersonList().size(); ++i) { 
            if (getPersonList().get(i) instanceof Reader) {
                p = getPersonList().get(i);
                if (p.getName().equals(name))
                    return false;
            }

        }
        break;

    case "Provider":
        p = new Provider(null, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < getPersonList().size(); ++i) { 
            if (getPersonList().get(i) instanceof Provider) {
                p = getPersonList().get(i);
                if (p.getName().equals(name))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        return false;

    }

    person.setName(name);
    person.setPw(pw);

    return true;
}

public void subscribeNew() throws IOException {
    if (subscribe(person.getTopic()) == true)
        context.redirect("indexReader.xhtml");
}

public List<Person> getPersonList() {
    personList = personEJB.findPerson();
    return personList;
}

public String addNewPerson() {
    person = personEJB.addPerson(person);
    personList = personEJB.findPerson();
    return "employeeList.xhtml";
}

public void registerNew() throws IOException {

    if (register(person.getName(), person.getPw(), person.getCheckPw(),
            person.getType()) == true) {
        person = personEJB.addPerson(person);
        personList = personEJB.findPerson();
        context.redirect("login.xhtml");
    }

    else {
        context.redirect("register.xhtml");
    }
}

public void loginNew() throws IOException {

    if (login(person.getName(), person.getPw()).getType().equals("Reader")) {
        if (login(person.getName(), person.getPw()) != null)
            context.redirect("indexReader.xhtml");
    } else if (login(person.getName(), person.getPw()).getType().equals(
            "Provider")) {
        if (login(person.getName(), person.getPw()) != null)
            context.redirect("indexProvider.xhtml");
    } else {
        context.redirect("login.xhtml");
    }
}

 public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "login?faces-redirect=true";
    }

//setters, getters

}
```

The EJB looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class PersonEJB {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "user")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Person> findPerson() {
        TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findPerson",
                Person.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public Person addPerson(Person person) {
        entityManager.persist(person);
        return person;
    }
}
```

The similar I have for News.

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findNews", query = "SELECT e FROM News e")


public class News implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String text;
private String category;
private String status;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created = new Date();

@PrePersist
private void onCreate() {
    created = new Date();
}

public News(String text, String category, String status) {
    this.text = text;
    this.category = category;
    this.status = status;
}
//setters, getters
```

What I want to do is get the Topic, that a person wants to subscribe and then show to the person just the news from the topic. I wrote something like this.

```
@Named(value = "newsController")
@RequestScoped
@SessionScoped

@ManagedBean(name="news")
public class NewsController implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EJB
private NewsEJB newsEJB;
private News news = new News(null, null, null);
private List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<News> filteredNews = new ArrayList<>();

private List<String> myTopics = new ArrayList<>();

private String topic;
private Person person = new Person();

public boolean subscribe(String topic) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getNewsList().size(); i++) 
        if (getNewsList().get(i).getCategory().contains(topic)) {
            person.getMyTopics().add(topic);
            return true;
        }

            return false;
        }


public List<News> getFilteredNews(){
    News e = new News();
    if(subscribe(topic)==true){
    for(int i =0;i < getNewsList().size(); i++){
        topic = getMyTopics().get(i);
        if (getNewsList().get(i).getCategory().equals(topic)){
            filteredNews = newsEJB.findNews();
            newsEJB.addNews(e);
            filteredNews.add(e);
        }
    }
    }

    return filteredNews;
}


public void subscribeNew() throws IOException{
        getFilteredNews();
        context.redirect("foundTopics.xhtml");
}


public List<News> getNewsList() {
    newsList = newsEJB.findNews();
    return newsList;
}

public void publishNews() throws IOException {
    News akt = new News(news.getText(), news.getCategory(),
            news.getStatus());
    newsList = newsEJB.findNews();
    newsEJB.addNews(akt);
    context.redirect("indexProvider.xhtml");
}

//setters and getters
```

And the EJB class for news similar as the above one

```
public class NewsEJB {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "user")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<News> findNews() {
        TypedQuery<News> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findNews",
                News.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public News addNews(News news) {
        entityManager.persist(news);
        return news;
    }
}
```

Where the boolean subscribe() should get the topic I subscribe in new arraylist. Then compare the topics from this arraylist in the getFilteredNews() and show just the news with these topics. And subscribeNew() get the filteredNews and return to foundtopics.xhtml. But this is always a nullpointerexception.

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong? Do I have to join the 2 tables first? And how should I do, that this arraylist with the subscribes topics whould be saved for each person? I think for each person different.

Comment: Why are there so many nasty annotations before the managed bean classes `@Named(value = "newsController")`, `@RequestScoped`, `@SessionScoped`, `@ManagedBean(name="news")`? `ExternalContext` should not be stored as an instance member.

Comment: Hm, I am not really sure at this, I was just trying to make something functional. :/

Comment: Are you aware of the fact the `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` are almost the same? `@Named` overwrites the value given by `@ManagedBean` to use that bean name in your `el expression`. If you're using jEE6+ i'd suggest to use `@Named`. And you're also mixing different scopes for the same bean. This doesn't seem like good practice to me. I'm not sure if it's theoretically possible though..

Comment: So is there any way you would suggest me, should I do it?